# using strpos to return true if a string contains to any of the strings from a set

Tags: php, arrays, string, strpos

The only function I can use is strpos, say I have set of strings:
`cat
dog
elephant`

and I want to know if a keyword contains either to any of the strings above.

`for at => True (contains inside cat)
for og => True (contains inside dog)
for asdasd => False (contains inside elephant)`

I tried this:

`strpos("keyword",("cat" || "dog" || "elephant"))`

but no luck.

Hope somebody can help

Comment: @larsmans it is actually php-based. So PHP could help.

Comment: @nneonneo can you please give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any restrictions on your keyword and strings? If they will never contain a certain character, say '~', then you can simply use this:

```
if (strpos(<your keyword>,implode('~',<array of strings>)) !== FALSE)
{
  <do something>
}
```

This cannot be used when you have no control over the characters in your keyword and strings. In that can you can check each string in the array seperately:

```
foreach (<array of strings> as $string)
{
  if (strpos(<your keyword>,$string) !== FALSE)
  {
     <do something>
  }
}
```

An array is clearly the way to go to store your strings.